# How to read my outlook mail using java and oauth2.0 with application regsitration in Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, outlook, office365

I am just trying to read my mail using java as shown in the code

[how-to-access-outlook-office365-com-imap-form-java-with-oauth2](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2022/10/24/how-to-access-outlook-office365-com-imap-form-java-with-oauth2/)

Also, aware of the documentations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-your-application
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application

and gone through SO threads.. and done the steps as mentioned (i hope i did correctly)...

- [How to access outlook.office365.com IMAP form Java with OAUTH2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157939/how-to-access-outlook-office365-com-imap-form-java-with-oauth2/74183227#74183227)
- [Cannot authenticate to IMAP on office365 using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73463357/cannot-authenticate-to-imap-on-office365-using-javamail)

I can fetch token using **client_credential** but I am still stuck in **A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed** error.

Though asking here to confirm that :

- **Is there any other way to read mails without registering Application in Azure AD ?**
- **Is there another way to get oauth token from another server instead mentioned above
  ?**

**Update 1:**

So far progressed..!

- App registration done (client_id, client_secret generated)
- API permission enabled: [IMAP.AccessAsApp, Mail.Read.All, Mail.Send.All] and status granted from admin.
- I can get my authentication token from **https://login.microsoftonline.com/tanantId/oauth2/v2.0/token** for client credential / password grant type

Comment: [What is the error message exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed... i will add additional info in **UPDATE 1** part..

Comment: @user10186832 udpated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For client credentials flow, you need to add application permissions under Office 365 Exchange Online

[image]

Make sure to grant admin consent for all the application permissions.

Once consent has been provided, the admin must register your AAD application's service principal in Exchange using powerShell by following commands:

**Install ExchangeOnlineManagement**

Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -allowprerelease
Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization

**Register Service Principal in Exchange:**

1.New-ServicePrincipal -AppId <APPLICATION_ID> -ServiceId <OBJECT_ID> [-Organization <ORGANIZATION_ID>]

*Make sure to use ObjectId from enterprise applications rather than object id of application registration.*
For the same application you registered in Application Registration. A corresponding application has been created in Enterprise Application as well. You need to pass object id from there while registering service principal in Exchange:
[image]

2.Get-ServicePrincipal | fl

3.Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "john.smith@contoso.com" -User
<SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess

In the application, you need to use scope = 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default'

Once you will get the access token, you can create and open a Java Mail connection to read mails.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.put("mail.imap.host", "outlook.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put("mail.imap.user", mailAddress);
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

    // open mailbox....
    String token = getAuthToken(tanantId,clientId,client_secret);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", mailAddress, token);
```

Comment: Thanks for your large answer i know it took some time to collect these information.. As i am not admin.. i am not sure about the enterprise application part... I have registered my application and done the same as you mentioned in **App registration**  tab... 
but What is **enterprise application** ? i cant create says no access...

Comment: I have updated my answer with another screenshot to get the object id from Enterprise application.

Comment: Yup ok got it... one more doubt... 3rd command with john.smith@contoso.com mail means.. i can access this mail only right ? .. i mean read / write ...!

Comment: Yes this mail id will be allowed to access by you application. I provided the sample mail id here. Also, I provided Mail.Read permission only above. So, this particular mail will get only read access. To get write access as well, you need to provide Mail.ReadWrite application permission.

Comment: I have this problem :

PS /home/david> Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -allowprerelease Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization
Install-Module: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Import-module'. This failure might be caused by applying the default parameter binding. You can disable the default parameter binding in $PSDefaultParameterValues by setting $PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"] to be $true, and retry. The following default parameter was successfully bound for this cmdlet when the error occurred: -Scope